# Is there an IC with a series of 2-input switches that can have all elements switch with one signal?

Tags: switches

I want to select either input A's 4 signals, or input B's 4 signals.
So I'm more interested in using 3-pin like switch, that can short circuit from the either A or B (not open or close one input)

Is there such IC that holds a series of 2-inputs switches, that can change the state of all at once, or should I just stick to a mux or program a CPLD?

[image]

Comment: Yes, there are chips.  Google "Analog Switch", or look for them on your favourite IC supplier (MAXIM, Analog Devices, Texas Instruments, etc).

Comment: If you are looking to switch digital logic, google "quad 2-input multiplexer".

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to switch digital logic, you are looking for a "quad 2-input multiplexer". There are many such devices available, so I recommend a Google search to find the right one for you.

An example is [74LVC157A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scas292q/scas292q.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with 2 SPST switches and tie the outputs together, or just use a DPDT analog mux like the Maxim 14689.  Picture snip below from Maxim datasheet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know you want exactly 4 inputs then there is definitely dedicated ICs you can by that serves the function you want but if you plan on modifying or scaling up your design at all you may want to consider building your own circuit using some basic tri-state buffers and OR gates. I made this one in about 5 minutes and you can just copy it for however many inputs you have. Just set whichever select input you want to '1' to have that output or both 0 for hi-Z.

Simple schematic:
[image: simple schematic]